# Office Update Won't Install

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I have several servers failing to install a security update for Office 2016 (KB5002521) 32-bit with error 0x8024002d. I've also read some articles saying this update actually breaks Office, so if I have to go back to the WSUS server and mark as Deny then I will. It has installed on other servers though and we have not heard of any issues. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I have already tried the following steps:

Ran SFC and DISM tools
Stopped services and renamed the SoftwareDistribution and catroot2 folders, restarted services.